# Why won't my HTML table respect the specified layout?

Tags: html, node.js, html-table, formatting, ejs

I am working with Node.js and have created a calendar page that should display 3 meal options for each day in an .ejs file. The calendar week is only 5 days long. I'm populating the meal options from my psql database and node model named `day`. I have specified the table to have 5 columns, but the 6th day is appearing next to the 5th instead of in the row below.

Here is the code I am currently working with:

```
<div class="calendarMonth">
    <table id="month" style="width:100%">
        <colgroup>
            <col span="5">
        </colgroup>

        <th colspan="5">October 2018</th>
        <tr>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <% days.forEach((day) => { %>
            <td>
                <%= day.id %><br>
                <%= day.mealOne %><br>
                <%= day.mealTwo %><br>
                <%= day.mealThree %><br>
            </td>
            <% }) %>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you want to add a new <tr>-element  after every 5 iterations.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `<tr></tr>` tag within your `forEach` block after every 5 days.

**EDIT**

Assuming `day.id` gives you day of week, you can modify your code like this:

```
<div class="calendarMonth">
    <table id="month" style="width:100%">
        <colgroup>
            <col span="5">
        </colgroup>

        <th colspan="5">October 2018</th>
        <tr>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
        </tr>

        <% days.forEach((day) => { %>

        <% if(day.id == "Monday") { %>
        <tr>
        <% } %>

            <td>
                <%= day.id %><br>
                <%= day.mealOne %><br>
                <%= day.mealTwo %><br>
                <%= day.mealThree %><br>
            </td>

        <% if(day.id == "Monday") { %>
        </tr>
        <% } %>

        <% }) %>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what this would look like?

Comment: Check now. Updated the answer